# React Native Navigation Android Actionbar Image

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation and have found for iOS I can do the following to add an image to the UINavigationController

```
componentDidMount()  {    
  this.props.navigator.setTitle({
  title: "",
  titleImage: images.logo,
 });
}
```

But cannot find a way to add an image to the ActionBar in Android? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/103

It looks like they don't support image/icon next to title in android.

============================================

You can try setTitleImage.

```
    componentDidMount()  {    
      this.props.navigator.setTitle({
      title: ""
     });
      this.props.navigator.setTitleImage({
       titleImage: images.logo,
     });
    }
```

============================================

Check this. Use Push instead of setTitle.

https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/wiki/Screen-API

I have not tested the code, but I think u can try it.

Comment: I don't want to "push" a new view onto the Stack though. I want to set the image on my first screen. If I use this method then it will push to a new view?

Comment: Undefined is not an object

Comment: separate into 2 lines

Comment: Undefined is not an function (evaluating _platformSpecificDeprecated2.default.navigatorSetTitleImage(this.params)

Comment: They don't support image/icon next to title in android.

Comment: That sucks! There must be a way to do it natively?